# How to do basic causal inference for two random variables

Tags: random-variable, causality, mutual-information, granger-causality

Suppose that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Is it possible to detect the dependency $Y = f(X)$ for some arbitrary $f$? Is there a way of quantifying if $Y$ is "nearly equal" to $f(X)$?

I think this is to do with mutual information. I'm not quit clear on the exact relationship. It might be the mutual information *is* this measure I'm after. There's a measure called the rand-index, which seems to measure when it is simultaneously that case that $Y=f(X)$, $X=f(Y)$

**Edit:** The particular case I'm interested in has $X$ and $Y$ discrete (with a discrete - but large sample space) though I am also interested in infinite countable sample and value spaces (sequences of characters in particular).

Comment: MI would only measure association. This is inherently a causal inference problem. If these are time-series, Granger causality could be used.

Comment: @MehmetSuzen Thanks for the reply. I guess I'm just interesting in association for the moment (though I agree causality is useful). Does this mean that MI measures what I'm after?

Comment: Yes, then the question will be irrelevant.

Comment: Lol. Knowing that MI is a measure of when one random variable is a function of another one is relevant to me! (it may however be commonly known knowledge to many others)

Comment: I have rolled back your question to the previous version because erasing it to make a comment provides even less clarity.

Comment: Indeed. I agree that it's childish. I just find the whole "close happy" bureaucracy tiresome at times, and a little protest is necessary if only for one's own well being. It sometimes feel as if people want to just create process and fiddle with things for the sake of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

> How to do basic causal inference for two random variables?

If your data is [indexed by time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process), then you might consider [Granger causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) as has been suggested. Two of the commonly applied statistical frameworks of [causal inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_inference) today are the [Neyman-Rubin causal model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_causal_model) and [Judea Pearl's causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(book)). There is a less well-known technique called ["convergent cross-mapping"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22997134/) that attempts to reconstruct a latent state space assuming an attractor, however I will leave this topic aside.

One thing that both of these frameworks agree upon is the importance of [intervention](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/36444610_Interventions_and_Causal_Inference) (i.e. performing a manipulation or [experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiment)). They also both retrospectively justify the historical use of [controls in experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control).

Very few systems have only two variables to consider, but we can still use the interventionist view. We have three options:

- $X$ and $Y$ are causally unrelated
- $X$ causes $Y$
- $X$ is caused by $Y$

When I say "*$X$ causes $Y$*", what does that mean? It means that if we manipulate a change in $X$, that will result in a change in $Y$. The manipulation part is important because it is what distinguishes associational inferences from causal ones in this context.

So, to learn about causality between two variables, run experiments where you manipulate one and look for a response in the other. This is partly why design of experiments is important.

> Is it possible to detect the dependency $Y = f(X)$ for some arbitrary $f$?

Yes, there are many estimators of dependence between two random variables, including functions of random variables. As mentioned above, you could use [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). There are other estimators of specific types of dependence such as [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), but for any estimator you use you must be mindful of its assumptions. Before touching any estimators, I would recommend plotting the scatter plot between the variables to 'see' if there is anything potentially going on.

> Is there a way of quantifying if  is "nearly equal" to ()?

Yes, there are many. Some straightforward functions are [residual sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares), [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), [root-mean-square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), and [mean absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error). Somewhat more abstractly, you can consider any [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) to be an estimator of how closely $Y = f(X)$, which can include information-theoretic estimators such as [KLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and [JSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence).

> I think this is to do with mutual information. I'm not quit clear on the exact relationship.

The relationship is provable, although it requires some background in probability theory and information theory. Simply put

$$\text{MI}(X,Y) = 0 \iff X \perp \!\!\! \perp Y$$

which is to say that mutual information is always zero whenever the two variables are [mutually independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), and *vice versa*.

> There's a measure called the rand-index, which seems to measure when it is simultaneously that case that $Y=f(X)$, $X=f(Y)$

The [Rand index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) is suited to the use case where you can compute either a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) or a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) because it takes in finite count measures. The main area that I've seen the Rand index applied is in assessing the accuracy of clustering algorithms. If there variables you are dealing with are continuous, you can either attempt [to bin your variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) into [histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (which comes with binning error) or you can use an estimator other than the Rand index.

> Footnote: @Alexis provided a citation to an additional framework of causal inference that appears to work outside a counterfactual frame. See *Puccia, C. J., & Levins, R. (1986). Qualitative Modeling of Complex Systems: An Introduction to Loop Analysis and Time Averaging (C. J. Puccia & R. Levins, Eds.). Harvard University Press*.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added some additional information to my question. I'm really interested is discrete value spaces (I was trying to apply a method to a contingency table)

Could you give me a little more information about $MI$. I'm more interesting in the case that $X$ completely determines $Y$, which means when $MI(X, Y) \ne 0$. Does a large value of $MI(X, Y)$ suggest that X determines Y, how large, can I get a confidence interval on this hypothesis?

Comment: Discrete mutual information is given by $I(X;Y) = \sum_{y} \sum_{x} P_{(X,Y)}(x,y) log\left( \frac{P_{(X,Y)}(x,y) }{P_X(x)P_Y(y)} \right)$. [Gray 1977](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001999587790434X) made some study out of the maximum value, but my understanding is that it will depend on the event space.

Comment: The word "determines" is a little ambiguous. If you don't mean "causality", then I would advise you to make some study of [convergence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables).

Comment: For a confidence interval calculated from real data, you can perform either a bootstrap test or a permutation test depending on what assumption you're trying to test.

Comment: Thanks Galen, I think I need to read a little to profitably interpret your help. Hopefully I'll get round to doing this over the weekend.

Comment: Please note, as mentioned in the comments to the question, Mutual Information (MI) can not resolve if  Y=f(X) or X=f(Y). There is no causal direction in MI.

Comment: @MehmetSuzen Agreed. Near the top of my answer I direct the poster to Neyman-Rubin and Pearl who give nuanced treatments of causality, but isn't clear to me that the poster is interested in causality despite the question in the original post.

Comment: @Galen I didn't mention causality in the original post . It was edited: (https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/533627/revisions). My framing is not exactly causual. In my example $X=g_X(Z)$, $Y=g_Y(Z)$, where g_X and g_Y are different labelling tasks.... I want to know if one labelling tasks implies another. I can't exactly vary $X$ and see the rsult on $Y$, I can only vary $Z$.

Comment: @AttRigh Thank you for the correction. I have not checked the edit history.

Comment: @AttRigh You can check if [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) holds on propositions concerning labels. It usually doesn't. You could also look at the probability of implication $P(A \implies B)$, or even try out [conditional event algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_event_algebra) if you wish to treat conditional probability as equivalent to the probability of implication.

Comment: –1 For inaccurate characterization of available methods of causal inference. See for example, Puccia, C. J., & Levins, R. (1986). *Qualitative Modeling of Complex Systems: An Introduction to Loop Analysis and Time Averaging* (C. J. Puccia & R. Levins, Eds.). Harvard University Press which provides methods for inference (and deduction) of causal systems which, for example, the counterfactual formal causal inference framework **cannot** analyze. Decent answer otherwise.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks for the feedback! I am not familiar with this work, but I will add it to my reading list.

Comment: Might I suggest "Two of the commonly applied statistical frameworks…" as an entirely palatable alternative. :)

Comment: @Alexis I have edited the post as per your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: Also: in addition to your options: (1) *X* is causally maintained in equilibrium by unmodeled variables, *X* causes *Y*, and *Y* causes *X*; (2) *X* causes *Y*, *Y* is causally maintained in equilibrium by unmodeled variables, and *Y* causes *X*; (3) *X* is causally maintained in equilibrium by unmodeled variables, *X* causes *Y*, *Y* is causally maintained in equilibrium by unmodeled variables, and *Y* causes *X*. Food for thought… :)

Comment: @Alexis I am unfamiliar with this jargon. Is this covered in the source you cited? Perhaps I should put that source in a footnote of my answer so it is easier to find.

Comment: Oh! Not suggesting an additional edit, but am pointing out that there are ideas in causal inference you have not touched on. Just trying to whet your appetite. :D